# Connector/J error after upgrade mysql to version 8

Tags: jdbc, wolfram-mathematica, jconnect, mysql-8.0

### Problem:

I upgraded mysql to newest version:

```
127.0.0.1$ mysql -V 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 8.0.0-dmr, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Now I cannot connect with `mysql` by `jdbc` using driver `connector/j` in program `mathematica`. When I am trying do this, then I see exception:

```
JDBC::error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

### Debugging that I done

In purpose to debug I installed oldest `mysql` on virtual machine.

```
192.168.43.48$ mysql -V
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

And connection with oldest `mysql` was done correctly.

You can see commands initializing connections and these results on the screen:

[image: error.png]

My Mathematica uses the following version of `JDBC` and `Connector/J`:

- JDBC has version 3
- Connector/J has 5.1.27

I am obtaining these info by execution command (in `mathematica` not `bash`):

```
JDBCDrivers["MySQL(Connector/J)"]
```

that gives output:

```
JDBCDriver["Name" -> "MySQL(Connector/J)", 
"Driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "Protocol" -> "jdbc:mysql://", 
 "Version" -> 3., 
 "Description" -> 
  "MySQL using Connector/J - Version 5.1.27 - This supports all known \
MySQL server versions.", 
 "Location" -> 
  "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/\
DatabaseResources/mysql.m"]
```

I append info about java version:

```
127.0.0.1$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Should I upgrade `jdbc`, `connector/j`, or downgrade `mysql`? Maybe is there another solution?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Connector/J, version 5.1.27 is relatively old.

Comment: Connectors in Mathematica are placed in `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java`, but simple removing file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar` and pasting file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connector/J 5.x will not connect to a MySQL 8.x database; you have to use the 8.0.x Connector/J driver.

Note that with the 8.0.x Connector/J driver the classpath also changed, from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.